# No puedo resolver este problema

Tags: android, gradle

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo un problema con el gradle. Ya intente en la opción de "Sync project with gradle files" y otras opciones pero no puedo resolverlo

Comment: Bienvenido, no se ve bien la imagen, cual es el error, por favor especifica, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: Por una parte me sale el error "Se ha anulado una conexión establecida por el software en su equipo host", leí que reiniciando android se componía pero me sigue saliendo el error. Por otra parte me sale "Gradle project sync failed", ya intente varias opciones como la opcion que puse, también descargue un gradle de internet e intente sincronizarlo desde android pero nada